# How implement FMX HD app zoom-in and zoom-out?

Tags: delphi, zooming, firemonkey

I am a newbie at FireMonkey. Recently i'm using Delphi(FMX) to develop a small `2D` game, and i want to add the ZOOM-in/out effect when wheeling mouse, I tried, and searched Idera sample and FMX codes, no gain.
So, is there any way to implement ZOOM? and why FMX do not offer easy-use "scale" properties? FMX is not user friendly, and Very lack of mature products, sample codes and discussions.
Thanks very much, and forgive me for my poor English.

**Let it be simple:**

`File-->New-->Multi-Device Application-->Blank Application`, click OK, then we should get a FMX HD App, and what i want to do is, when i am wheeling the mouse, the main form's viewport can zoom-in/out.

```
    procedure TForm1.FormMouseWheel(Sender: TObject; Shift: TShiftState;
      WheelDelta: Integer; var Handled: Boolean);
    begin
      // ?
    end;
```

Sorry for my poor description, thank you!

Comment: You ask: *why FMX do not offer easy-use "scale" properties?* Instead of searching sample codes, search the docs. E.g. [TControl.Scale](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE7/en/FMX.Controls.TControl.Scale).

Comment: my fault tom, i mean, how can i scale the form/canvas while not change it's size, and they're not TControl, like viewport/cliprect, etc

Comment: You need to clarify your question and provide a simplified example of your form and what you have on the form, if not `TControl`s or descendants.

Comment: From your public data I can see that you have been around since my last comment, yet you have not edited your question based on my last comment. Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and edit your question with concrete details that are important for you. I do have a solution ready for you, but I can't post it if I can't be sure it answers your requirements.

Comment: sorry Tom, i just working all the afternoon, and i do not notice your post, sorry! The question has been edit, if it's not clear, i'd edit it for more times. I am not familiar with stackoverflow, in our country(China) we have our tech forums, but as you know, we do not know FMX much. sorry && Thank you.

Comment: No problem, Stack Overflow is indeed different from forums. Please visit the [tour] for a short introduction and read it all, it takes maybe 2 minutes. It describes what you can ask about and what your options are after somebody answers your question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Place a `TScaledLayout` (named `ScaledLayout1` in the following) on the form, and set the `Align` property to `Client`. Also, set `HitTest = True` to receive mouse events anywhere on the layout. Then place all other controls on this layout.

Create an `OnMouseWheel()` event for the `ScaledLayout1` layout (named `ScaledLayout1MouseWheel` in the following).

Declare a private field on the form

```
private
  StoredWheelDelta: extended;
```

This is needed to accumulate scroll amounts.

And then write the code for the `OnMouseWheel()` event:

```
procedure TForm12.ScaledLayout1MouseWheel(Sender: TObject; Shift: TShiftState;
  WheelDelta: Integer; var Handled: Boolean);
begin
  StoredWheelDelta := StoredWheelDelta + WheelDelta; // accumulate wheeldelta's

  ScaledLayout1.Scale.X := (1 + StoredWheelDelta / 120 / 10);
  ScaledLayout1.Scale.Y := (1 + StoredWheelDelta / 120 / 10);
end;
```

The values 120 and 10 are just to scale the change to a reasonable value. 120 is the same as a typical value of `WheelDelta` and 10 reduces the change to a tenth.

Comment: Thank you very much Tom, you offered an excellent solution, i'll try it, thank you for your detailed reply and enthusiasm!